# Reconcile links and pathfiles for the Kaldi recipes

Tags: linux, hyperlink, kaldi

I'm using the Kaldi toolset for speech recognition from a computer in which I don't have the rights to modify the contents of the install in `/var/kaldi`. The directory contains a folder of scripts that are provided as a sample of utilisation, the scripts are also heavily linked to each other.

The structure is as follows, the main scripts folder for dataset `mydataset` is found in `/var/kaldi/egs/mydataset/v1/`, where scripts such as `run.sh` or `path.sh` are located. In particular, the user is expected to run the `run.sh`script which then calls `path.sh` which then exports a `KALDI_ROOT` variable:

```
export KALDI_ROOT=`pwd`/../../..
```

The scripts folder also contains many links that point to folders in other scripts' locations, so that scripts can be re-used if the're not changed. An example would be for the `local` entry in `v2` to point to the `local` folder in `v1` as follows:

```
IntxLNK^A.^@.^@/^@v^@1^@/^@l^@o^@c^@a^@l^@/^@
```

or

```
../v1/local/
```

I have to run the scripts from a folder I've been given somewhere else in the sytem as in`myfolder/egs/mydataset/v2/`.

---

**How can I modify `path.sh` and/or link to the installation folder so that I can run everything located in the intended kaldi root `/var/kaldi`, but also link to the rest of the scripts in `myfolder/egs`?**

Answer (score 1):

After talking with the admin of the system, the solution is to rebuild each link one by one to point to the new scripts locations. I'll leave the answer unanswered in case someone wants to add something else. Also, feel free to delete the question if you believe it not to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make a ProgramFiles directory in home i.e. ~/ProgramFiles

There I make folders for all programs I want to install or git-clone.

In path.sh I always use the whole /home//ProgramFiles/kaldi as root. Defnining absolute path helps overcome many errors along the way. You may have to define DATA_ROOT at some points in your path.sh